# Sending Data Between 2 Android Phones Via Wifi

Tags: android

How can i send data (variable or media) from 1 phone to another using wifi?
And how would i know when it's done transferring?

TY!!!!

Comment: what have you researched on the subject?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [AllJoyn](http://developer.qualcomm.com/dev/alljoyn-p2p/faq) peer-to-peer library. It probably has all the features you need. If you need peer-to-peer communication, it will be difficult to implement a robust solution yourself.

An alternative will be to use a server that will orchestrate the transfer.